# Script Produces "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'scrollHeight')" When Iframe is Reloaded

Tags: javascript, iframe

I added the highlighted script to my PHP page's header to automatically adjust iframe size to iframe contents; the script is activated w/ `<script>sizeit("#frame_id");</script>`, and the results are as expected / it works well.

However, on iframe reload (w/ a "right-click / Reload iframe" selection within the iframe) the script produces the following error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'scrollHeight')"

It seems scrollHeight isn't available on iframe reload.

```
<script>
function sizeit(id){
    let iframe = document.querySelector(id);

    iframe.addEventListener('load', function() {
        setInterval(function() {
            iframe.style.height = iframe.contentDocument.body.scrollHeight + 10 + 'px';
            iframe.style.width = 100 + '%';
        });
    });
}
</script>
```

Any thoughts on how to resolve this? The error message does not appear when the entire page is reloaded, only when an iframe is reloaded.

Comment: You might get more efficiently working code, if you'd adjust the height of the iframe from inside its document.

Comment: Interesting ... Are you suggesting actively passing <div> height from iframe content page to the parent page containing the iframe?

Comment: Something like that, you have to call the function in the main window every time you actually make chages to the size only, no interval is needed.

Comment: The reason for the error is probably that the interval hits to the page refresh at the time `body` is not loaded yet.

Comment: That's exactly right ... Window: load event ... "The load event is fired when the _whole page has loaded_ ... " See: [link]https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/load_event[/link] ... So, scrollHeight isn't available when it's needed.  Thing is, without rewriting some code I do need interval.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/load_event

Comment: The error message actually tells that `iframe.contentDocument.body` is `null`.

Comment: Rewrote some code ... Got rid of interval ... Problem solved ... Thanks for the assist!